# Disabling click/select on certain options in dropdown depending on a condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select

HTML (view side):

```
<select ng-model="selectedValue" ng-change="updateSelectedValue(selectedValue)">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

controller side:

```
$scope.availValue = product.qty //It's dynamic, getting updated on an API call

$scope.updateSelectedValue = function(currentSelectedValue) {
    if(currentSelectedValue > $scope.availValue) {
      //write code such that if this condition is true than do not let the user click/select options whose value is greater than $scope.availValue, i.e. disable those options
      //just display all options but do not let the user click/select   those options whose value is exceeding $scope.availValue
    }
};
```

Example:

```
     $scope.selectedValue = 7;

     $scope.availVal = 4;
```

Expected Output: Display all 10 options but do not let the user click/select options having values more than 4.

Comment: The problem seems a bit unclear to me. If you select something from the dropdown why you want to restrict that dropdown again to select other value. Is it for one dropdown or there are two dropdowns? Let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this:

```js
var app = angular.module("Demo", []);

app.controller("AppController", function($scope) {
  $scope.ddlValues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
  $scope.availVal = 4;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="Demo">
  <div ng-controller="AppController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="availVal" />
    <br/><br/>
    <select ng-model="selectedValue">
      <option value="">--Select--</option>
      <option ng-repeat="val in ddlValues" ng-value="val" ng-disabled="val > availVal">{{ val }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sktajbir/6fmvsaf0/15/

What is happening here is, it is watching availVal and disabled those option which are over availVal. Hope this will help you to achieve your goal. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use disable property from option tag.

```
<select ng-model="selectedValue">
    <option value="1" ng-disabled="isDisabled(1)">1</option>
    <option value="2" ng-disabled="isDisabled(2)">2</option>
    <option value="3" ng-disabled="isDisabled(3)">3</option>
    <option value="4" ng-disabled="isDisabled(4)">4</option>
    <option value="5" ng-disabled="isDisabled(5)">5</option>
    <option value="6" ng-disabled="isDisabled(6)">6</option>
    <option value="7" ng-disabled="isDisabled(7)">7</option>
    <option value="8" ng-disabled="isDisabled(8)">8</option>
    <option value="9" ng-disabled="isDisabled(9)">9</option>
    <option value="10" ng-disabled="isDisabled(10)">10</option>
</select>
```

Controller:

```
  $scope.isDisabled= function(value) {
      return value > $scope.availVal;
  };
```

You can test here: http://jsfiddle.net/9dpepxak/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code:

```
<select ng-model="selectedValue" ng-change="updateSelectedValue(selectedValue)">
            <option ng-disabled="1 > availValue " value="1">1</option>
            <option ng-disabled="2 > availValue " value="2">2</option>
            <option ng-disabled="3 > availValue " value="3">3</option>
            <option ng-disabled="4 > availValue " value="4">4</option>
            <option ng-disabled="5 > availValue " value="5">5</option>
            <option ng-disabled="6 > availValue " value="6">6</option>
            <option ng-disabled="7 > availValue " value="7">7</option>
            <option ng-disabled="8 > availValue " value="8">8</option>
            <option ng-disabled="9 > availValue " value="9">9</option>
            <option ng-disabled="10 > availValue " value="10">10</option>
        </select>
```